# Angular 12, i18n falha com scss

Tags: angular, scss, i18n

Estou tentando usar um template que comprei com internacionalização, mas estou tendo problemas quando executo o comando `ng server --conficuration=pt` simplesmente obtenho erros nos arquivos de scss e less:

```
 ng serve --configuration=pt

- Generating browser application bundles...
****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |    Size
main.js               | main          | 0 bytes
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 0 bytes
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 0 bytes
runtime.js            | runtime       | 0 bytes

| Initial Total | 0 bytes

Build at: 2021-05-23T12:42:56.501Z - Hash: ae91f0d387ebb27eaf71 - Time: 40288ms

Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  .custom-file-input:lang(en) ~ .custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang

assets/scss/_variable.scss - Error: assets/scss/_variable.scss from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\_variable.scss:297:10: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser [assets/scss/_variable.scss:297,10]
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/mixins/_padding-margin.scss - Error: assets/scss/mixins/_padding-margin.scss from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\mixins\_padding-margin.scss:11:22: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser [assets/scss/mixins/_padding-margin.scss:11,22]
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/rtl/_rtl-padding-margin.scss - Error: assets/scss/rtl/_rtl-padding-margin.scss from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\rtl\_rtl-padding-margin.scss:9:34: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser [assets/scss/rtl/_rtl-padding-margin.scss:9,34]
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/rtl/_spacing-rtl.scss - Error: assets/scss/rtl/_spacing-rtl.scss from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\rtl\_spacing-rtl.scss:6:13: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser [assets/scss/rtl/_spacing-rtl.scss:6,13]
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/widgets/_topbar-mail.scss - Error: assets/scss/widgets/_topbar-mail.scss from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\widgets\_topbar-mail.scss:9:4: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser [assets/scss/widgets/_topbar-mail.scss:9,4]
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.decl (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:201:16)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:115:18)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)

assets/scss/core/extra/_extra.scss - Error: assets/scss/core/extra/_extra.scss from Css Minimizer
Error: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.
    at C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\core\extra\_extra.scss:524:2
    at Root._error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:174:16)
    at Root.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\root.js:43:19)
    at Parser.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:740:21)
    at Parser.expected (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1129:19)
    at Parser.pseudo (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:875:19)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1080:14)
    at Parser.loop (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1039:12)
    at new Parser (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:164:10)
    at Processor._root (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:53:18)
    at Processor._runSync (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:100:21)

assets/scss/core/tables/_table-pages.scss - Error: assets/scss/core/tables/_table-pages.scss from Css Minimizer
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
    at C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\core\tables\_table-pages.scss:101:1
    at Root._error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:174:16)
    at Root.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\selectors\root.js:43:19)
    at Parser.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:740:21)
    at Parser.unexpected (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:758:17)
    at Parser.combinator (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:656:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1097:14)
    at Parser.loop (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:1039:12)
    at new Parser (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\parser.js:164:10)
    at Processor._root (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:53:18)
    at Processor._runSync (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss-selector-parser\dist\processor.js:100:21)

assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_animated.less - Error: assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_animated.less from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\icons\font-awesome\less\_animated.less:4:4: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_animated.less:4,4]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_bordered-pulled.less - Error: assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_bordered-pulled.less from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\icons\font-awesome\less\_bordered-pulled.less:4:4: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_bordered-pulled.less:4,4]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_core.less - Error: assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_core.less from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\icons\font-awesome\less\_core.less:4:4: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_core.less:4,4]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_fixed-width.less - Error: assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_fixed-width.less from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\icons\font-awesome\less\_fixed-width.less:3:4: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_fixed-width.less:3,4]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_icons.less - Error: assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_icons.less from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\icons\font-awesome\less\_icons.less:4:4: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_icons.less:4,4]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)

assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_larger.less - Error: assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_larger.less from Css Minimizer
C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\assets\scss\icons\font-awesome\less\_larger.less:5:3: Unknown word
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser [assets/scss/icons/font-awesome/less/_larger.less:5,3]
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
    at Input.error (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:123:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:518:22)
    at Parser.other (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
    at parse (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:11:12)
    at new LazyResult (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:122:16)
    at Processor.process (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:33:12)
    at cssnanoMinify (eval at transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:34:28), <anonymous>:51:61)
    at minify (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:15:32)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\angular\myApp\node_modules\css-minimizer-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:35:24)
```

sendo que se rodar apenas `ng serve` o servidor builda normal e roda redondo, ou quando removo os arquivos da pasta **assets**. Sou novo em Angular mas me parece que o comando com a configuração tenta traduzir os arquivos de scss oq para mim não faz sentido. Então se for isso tem como desativar?
Minhas configurações são essas:

**angular.js**

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
      "myApp": {
        "i18n": {
          "sourceLocale":"en-US",
          "locales": {
            "pt": {
              "translation": "src/locale/messages.pt.xlf",
              "baseHref": ""
            }
          }
        },
        "projectType": "application",
        "schematics": {
          "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "style": "scss"
          },
          "@schematics/angular:application": {
            "strict": true
          }
        },
        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "prefix": "app",
        "architect": {
          "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
            "options": {
              "outputPath": "dist/myApp",
              "index": "src/index.html",
              "main": "src/main.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
              "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ],
              "styles": [
                "src/styles.scss",
                "src/assets/scss/style.scss"
              ],
              "scripts": []
            },
            "configurations": {
              "pt": {
                "localize": ["pt"],
                "outputPath": "dist/pt",
                "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
              },
              "production": {
                "budgets": [
                  {
                    "type": "initial",
                    "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                    "maximumError": "1mb"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                    "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                    "maximumError": "4kb"
                  }
                ],
                "fileReplacements": [
                  {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                  }
                ],
                "outputHashing": "all"
              },
              "development": {
                "buildOptimizer": false,
                "optimization": false,
                "vendorChunk": true,
                "extractLicenses": false,
                "sourceMap": true,
                "namedChunks": true
              }
            },
            "defaultConfiguration": "production"
          },
          "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "browserTarget": "myApp:build:production"
              },
              "development": {
                "browserTarget": "myApp:build:development"
              },
              "pt": {
                "browserTarget": "myApp:build:pt"
              }
            },
            "defaultConfiguration": "development"
          },
          "extract-i18n": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build"
            }
          },
          "test": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
            "options": {
              "main": "src/test.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
              "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ],
              "styles": [
                "src/styles.scss"
              ],
              "scripts": []
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "defaultProject": "myApp"
  }
```

vou por um trecho da linha que recebo de erro:
***_variable.scss***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica, do que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score -2):

Depois de muito pesquisar, encontrei meu erro. No arquivo ***angular.js*** no server em configurations eu adicionei no pt o "optimization":false e começou a rodar.

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyApp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "MyApp:build:development"
            },
            "pt": {
              "browserTarget": "MyApp:build:pt",
              "optimization":false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

funcionou mas ainda recebo um warn dizendo que o optimization está depreciado. Alguma sugestão definitiva?